# Select second element of an selector

Tags: jquery

i have an code like that

```
<div class="aa">
    <div class="bb">
        <a href="gfdfdfddffgf.html">
            first text
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="aa">
    <div class="bb">
        <a href="gfdffdgf.html">
            second text
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="aa">
    <div class="bb">
        <a href="gfdfdfdfgf.html">
            another tert
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

i need to check if "first text" its equal to "second text"

class aa and bb are used elsewhere in the code so i need to use $('.aa .bb a').first().text() to get the "first text" but i dont know how to select "second text"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get matching element at a specific index

```js
const $a = $('.aa .bb a'),
      firstText = $a.first().text().trim(),
      secondText = $a.eq(1).text().trim()
      
console.log([firstText, secondText, secondText === firstText])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aa">
    <div class="bb">
        <a href="gfdfdfddffgf.html">
            first text
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="aa">
    <div class="bb">
        <a href="gfdffdgf.html">
            second text
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="aa">
    <div class="bb">
        <a href="gfdfdfdfgf.html">
            another tert
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```